# What version of Vue am I running in Nuxt 2.14.0?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to identify if my Nuxt app (2.14.0) is using Vue 2 or Vue 3, and I cannot tell. I have dived through `node_modules` and looked at my lock file but can't say for certain. I *think* it's using only Vue 2 -- specifically `vue "^2.6.12` -- based on what I can tell in the lock file.

Does anyone know which version of Vue that Nuxt is using in version 2.14.0 ? I tried reading through [this issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/5708) to better understand when / if Vue 3 has been introduced and release publicly in Nuxt.js but it sounds like Vue 3 is not incorporated inside any release of Nuxt.js.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The current versions of nuxt.js are still using vue 2.6.x, and to make it work with vue 3 main  feature (composition api), you should use the module called [`composition-api.nuxtjs`](https://composition-api.nuxtjs.org/), as you can see in the introduction they say:

> `@nuxtjs/composition-api` provides a way to use the Vue 3 Composition API in with Nuxt-specific features.

Comment: Thank you @Boussadjra Brahim -- I was actually trying to install swiper js, https://swiperjs.com/vue/, which requires Vue 3. I'm not too sure if there's a work around here unless Vue 3 is used instead of Vue 2 in nuxt.js.

Comment: i think you should install an older version of swiper which could be compatible with vue 3

Comment: That sounds like a good suggestion. But in fact, I found something that works for me https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-awesome-swiper -- looks like it allows you to use Vue 2 and Swiper JS

Comment: This is a semi-good answer, problem is, 5 seconds after it is posted, this fact may have changed. There must be some way to find out which version nuxt is using now?

Comment: Until now, the nuxt 3 which will be based on vue 3 has not released yet, I'm watching the news in Github and Twitter and I'll edit my answer when there'll be a new version

Comment: But, what is the way to identify the Vue version the nuxtjs im using

Comment: @Jovylle to get the exact version of any library, check the `node_modules` folder to look for your library's package.json. For example at `node_modules/vue/package.json`.

Comment: Thank you Vitamin Water I really need you in my life.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try `npm why vue` and check for the lines about nuxt (yarn works exactly the same too: `yarn why vue`)

```
vue@2.6.14
node_modules/@nuxt/vue-renderer/node_modules/vue
  vue@"^2.6.12" from @nuxt/vue-renderer@2.15.8
  node_modules/@nuxt/vue-renderer
    @nuxt/vue-renderer@"2.15.8" from nuxt@2.15.8
    node_modules/nuxt
      nuxt@"^2.15.8" from the root project
    @nuxt/vue-renderer@"2.15.8" from @nuxt/server@2.15.8
    node_modules/@nuxt/server
      @nuxt/server@"2.15.8" from nuxt@2.15.8
      node_modules/nuxt
        nuxt@"^2.15.8" from the root project
      @nuxt/server@"2.15.8" from @nuxt/core@2.15.8
      node_modules/@nuxt/core
        @nuxt/core@"2.15.8" from nuxt@2.15.8
        node_modules/nuxt
          nuxt@"^2.15.8" from the root project

vue@2.6.14
node_modules/@nuxt/vue-app/node_modules/vue
  vue@"^2.6.12" from @nuxt/vue-app@2.15.8
  node_modules/@nuxt/vue-app
    @nuxt/vue-app@"2.15.8" from nuxt@2.15.8
    node_modules/nuxt
      nuxt@"^2.15.8" from the root project
    @nuxt/vue-app@"2.15.8" from @nuxt/builder@2.15.8
    node_modules/@nuxt/builder
      @nuxt/builder@"2.15.8" from nuxt@2.15.8
      node_modules/nuxt
        nuxt@"^2.15.8" from the root project
  peer vue@"^2.0.0" from vuex@3.6.2
  node_modules/@nuxt/vue-app/node_modules/vuex
    vuex@"^3.6.2" from @nuxt/vue-app@2.15.8
    node_modules/@nuxt/vue-app
      @nuxt/vue-app@"2.15.8" from nuxt@2.15.8
      node_modules/nuxt
        nuxt@"^2.15.8" from the root project
      @nuxt/vue-app@"2.15.8" from @nuxt/builder@2.15.8
      node_modules/@nuxt/builder
        @nuxt/builder@"2.15.8" from nuxt@2.15.8
        node_modules/nuxt
          nuxt@"^2.15.8" from the root project
```

So nuxt@2.15.8 uses vue@2.6.14 for my example.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking at this thread now do know that currently Nuxt 2 use Vue 2.7.x so composition API is within your reach now :)